# How to insert a newline character in a jupyter notebook cell when using find and replace?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, replace, jupyter-notebook, find-replace

So I need to make changes in multiple cells in a Jupyter notebook. One of these changes is inserting a newlines in a code line.

`fig = fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=0.3, gridcolor='LightBlue')  fig.show()`

This line of code is present in multiple cells in the notebook. I need to insert a newline before `fig.show()` for the code to work.

I guess I need to use "find and replace" functionality.  But I am unable to insert a new line. I have tried using the regex [image: Find replace with regex]

But the output is `\nfig.show()`.

How can I insert a newline character in multiple cells in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know how to add a newline, but two possible workaraounds for your case:

1. Replace `fig.show()` with `(fig := fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=0.3, gridcolor='LightBlue')).show()`, i.e. chaining the two commands using the walrus operator so that `fig` is also updated
2. Put a `;` between both commands: Replace `fig.show()` with `fig = fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=0.3, gridcolor='LightBlue');fig.show()`

Comment: thanks. I have used the ; to make the notebook work but it doesnt seem like an elegant solution. will try the walrus operator.